# C# charting lib with different colors in a line graph

Tags: c#, graphs

I am looking for a charting library which can do a line graph, like this:
[image]

But allows different colors between Points, for example: between T1 and E2 i need Red, but between E2 and E3 i need the line to be blue, like this:

[image]

So far i only found librarys which can set the color for the whole line, but not individual parts of it.

Can someone recommend a library that can change the line color mid-graph?

Comment: To display on what  -Win Form, web etc?

Answer (score 0):

[Essential Chart for Windows Forms](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/chart) supports customizing line segment color.

[Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/153462/ze/153462-247611056.zip)

Note that Essential Studio is required to be installed for the sample to compile.

[image: Essential Chart with different colors for segments in line chart]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics for WPF controls can do that in a few lines of xaml. Blinded jnto an observable collection.

Use mvvm pattern when doing wpf with C#